# Cómo saber cuando se presiona el botón para desbloquear el teléfono

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Mi consulta es la siguiente , en android studio como haría para saber cuando el usuario presiona el botón para desbloquear el teléfono

Comment: Quizá , [busca esto](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_USER_PRESENT)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No se detectar específicamente cuando el usuario presiona el botón de desbloqueo pero si puedes saber cuando se prende o apaga la pantalla con un Bbroadcastreceiver:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 

{

BroadcastReceiver miBroadcast = new BroadcastReceiver() {    

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
            Log.i("TAG", "Screen ON");
        }
        else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
            Log.i("TAG", "Screen OFF");
        }

    }
};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //Aquí registras los eventos que quieres escuchar
    registerReceiver(miBroadcast, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON));
    registerReceiver(mybroadcast, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF));
}
}
```

Si lo quieres en background en lugar de un activity usa un `Service`

Comment: Creo que me servira ,Muchas gracias